# For loop CCSprites in CCScene tag check?

Tags: ios, for-loop, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am trying to put together a for loop in Cocos2D app that will loop through all the `CCSprite`'s in my scene checking for sprites with a tag of lets say 2.

Currently I have been trying to do this without any success or even idea where to start because I am not an expert with for loops in Cocos2D since I am not too familiar with its API's.

Do I need to have an if in the for loop? Is that the best thing to do? How should I even accomplish this?

Comment: If you're "not an expert with for loops" you probably want to grab K&R C first and only then start developing iOS apps. Also, what does 'check for sprites with a tag 2'? Should it store them? Delete them? Modify them? Display them? Or just log them using NSLog? Sorry, but your question doesn't really makes sense as it stands.

Comment: I just want to provide my own functionality for each ccsprite it returns. Also I am just not familiar with for loops with Cocos2D, I am good with normal Obj-C for loops. :) I am not that familiar with the Cocos2D API's, sorry if my post was unclear but I edited it for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CCArray *arr = [self children];

for(CCSprite *sprite in arr)
{
    if(2 == sprite.tag)
    {
        //do what you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, quick question, will this return sprites with  a tag of 2 that can be grandchildren, great grandchildren, etc... ?

Comment: @iBradApps of course it won't - this is a first-level check only. For what you want, you'll need to use recursion. But again, please: this is written in NSArray's class reference!